# PDF views stopped updating, no longer detecting errors

Tags: pdf, compiling, wrapfigure

Using windows 10, MikTex and TeXmaKer.

Have been using Latex for a while to make simple documents without many problems.

I was starting to learn how to use the wrapfigure environment. When i loaded \usepackage{wrapfig}, LaTex stopped detecting errors or updating the PDF. After restarting my computer, I have the same problem. For any LaTex file i load (even without the wrapfig package), an old pdf of the file loads in the viewer, but no changes to the pdf  occur when i click compile. Even worse, I type in some obviously awful code, click compile, and no error message occurs.

I have tried compiling the following simple code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
Hello
\end{document}
```

and i get the error message:

"Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Any idea what's gone wrong?

Comment: Can you add a screenshot of the `Commands` in `Configure TeXmaker`?

Comment: https://imgur.com/CI8Rqvg

Comment: Try checking the `Use a "build" subdirectory for output files` box. Not counting this box, my `Commands` is exactly the same with you.

Comment: Done. Now every time i try to compile I get the error message "Could not start the command.
pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex"

Comment: Well, I think the cause of the problem is the compiler (pdfLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, XeLaTeX...). [This](https://i.imgur.com/znyvieT.png) is my `Commands`. I can't see any difference.

Comment: In case the commands can't be run at all despite all your efforts, you should contact the owner of TeXmaker.

Comment: Forget for now TeXmaker and go discarding the possible causes of error one by one, starting by the most elemental.  (1) Start checking if there are still a "pdflatex" program in your hard disk, then if still works from the command prompt (that old black window with a  `C:\>`). Simply `cd` to your working directory and try `pdflatex hello.tex`. (3) If that work, center your attention in the editor configuration (3) Otherwise, center your atterion in the TeX configuration: (4) It works now adding the path to the program?  (i.e, c:\somewhere\pddlatex  hello.tex'`)?. An so on ...

Comment: There is a pdflatex file on my hard drive; when i open it it appears for only a second and then disappears again... i've been trying to uninstall miktex but having some problems (clicking the uninstall button doesnt seem to do anything and all the miktex files are still on my hard drive)... very confusing??

Comment: Don't try to deinstall or reinstall something. First try to check the state of your system. And don't double click on pdflatex.exe, that doesn't do anything - pdflatex is not an application with a GUI that you can start like this. Try to compile your file in some other editor (e.g. texworks, texstudio) or on the command line.

Comment: Sounds like your first issue was path got corrupted either 1) you or something changed name of MiKTeX path 2) something like reinstall skewed up 3) the path was getting too long and MiKTeX fell of the end.